# Permission for a quote?

Tags: copyright, quotes

Someone (not a particularly famous person,) said something during a podcast that I found would make a good quote, used in my upcoming book.

Do I need to get permission from the speaker or the podcast host?

I am pretty sure I don't, but wanted to make sure.

Is it considered bad form if I don't notify the speaker that I am quoting him in my book? The quote and subject matter are not controversial.

Comment: If you'd like, you can paraphrase the quote, and then skip attributing whoever said it. This sounds like it might be less complicated.

Comment: That's one option - but the name of the person give the quote more context and impact.

Comment: Good quotes have often been passed around. Google it, and see if it has a historic origin.  If the quote is really old, you might be in the clear (but citing the original source is still the correct etiquette).

Comment: Thanks - but the quote(s) I am looking at, are merely insightful for a particular industry - not a timeless quote that would be found on the internet. And the person who uttered the insightful sentence, their name would lend some weight to the credibility of the quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a lawyer and this is not legal advice. However,

If it's words on a podcast, then they've already put it out in public. Give attribution, e.g. in a footnote, and you should be good.

Now, a photo or illustration might be different. I'd probably ask permission (and I did, for one of the pictures in [here](https://www.albertcory.io/lets-do-have-hindsight)).